# Codeigniter Oauth2 integration with facebook

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

Hello i am facing a issue i just followed [This blog](https://bhaveshkhanpara.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/codeigniter-oauth-2-0-social-media-authentication/)

and created controller and views as mentioned in the blog now google Oauth provider is working fine but facebook provider gives a error screen(i have attached picture)[image]

I am not able to understand whether its a problem with facebook APP setup or something wrong with facebook app version.

Help needed.

Comment: i dont think its problem with facbook server because i am trying for this from last four days and facebook server is not down. the login for facebook works fine.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I thought of that but as i mentioned above i have exactly followed the blog. So thought of no need of providing code. Only thing i have changed in code is app id and app secreat.

Comment: okay lets assume, after an year.. someone will come here for the same error/issue, but blog link could die.. in that case your question will be no more useful in future hence we always encourage people to avoid link only questions/answers.

Comment: @RDC sorry for not uploading code because its around 6 pages and if i uploaded whole code i hope no body have patience to go through that and i will not get answer for that.
Any way i got the soultion for that it was mistake with FB app setup. I removed app from app settings and its working fine now.
Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear this, you should post as answer How did you resolved your issue, and don't forget to accept. please go through this.[Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)